# How to navigate to a website in javascript while providing a custom HTTP header?

Tags: javascript, http

I want to set a custom http header before navigating from one website to a another.

Here is a question and answer describing how to navigate in Javascript, but there is nothing in there about setting a header.  Nor can I find one after extensive searching.
[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

The only time you can set a custom HTTP header in browser-side JavaScript is when you use XMLHttpRequest. There is no way to do it when triggering browser navigation.